# Porque mis solicitudes al backend regresan el mismo dato varias veces?

Tags: angular, socket.io

Estoy usando socket.io para poder movilizar ciertos datos en mi aplicación, lo que estoy haciendo es un app que en tiempo real actualice si un usuario, está en línea y funciona a la perfeccion , lo que pasa es esto, te lo muestro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No podia ponerlo como texto o no se iba a entender, te explico, la lógica es la siguiente, lo que se actualiza es una lista de usuarios, cuando el servidor recibe alguna entrada en la función que actualiza el estado en la bd este hace un emit a Angular. Ahora mi inicio de sesión está en un componente atado a una ruta, la lista es un subcomponente de la ruta de mi componente home.
Cuando inicio sesión, en el servicio de auth uso esto y en mi servicio de home igual solo que con `this.socket.disconnect()`

```
this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{ transports : ['websocket' ] });
this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Conectado al servidor Socket.IO: ');
});
```

Como se que funciona, pues en la consola de mi back si llegan una sola ves los datos de connect y disconnect, ahora el codigo que se refresca es mi lista, es decir `lista.component.ts` el cual es llamada en el `home.component.html` , este componente lista hago lo siguiente:

```
  private friendsSubject: BehaviorSubject<Friend[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Friend[]>([]);

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookie: CookieService) {
this.socket = io('localhost:3000', { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });

this.socket.on('changeStatus', () => {
  console.log("reibido..")
  this.loadFriends()
 })
}

 getFriends(): Observable<Friend[]> {
    return this.friendsSubject.asObservable();
 }

 loadFriends() {
   if (this.cookie.check("token")) {
      this.http.get<Friend[]>(`${this.URL}friendStatus`).pipe(
         catchError(this.handleError),
      ).subscribe(
         friends => {
            this.friendsSubject.next(friends)
         })}
      }
```

Ese ultimo if protege mi peticion de ser llamada una ultima vez antes de que se quite la cookie en el metodo de logout pues como en este tambien actualiza el estado, actualiza la lista pero ya no para este usuario. En fin en mi `lista.component.html` recibo los datos que llegan:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.showFriends()
      this.initialFriendsLoad()
   }

   showFriends() {
     if(this.cookie.check("token")){
         this.listaService.getFriends().subscribe(
              response => {
                  console.log(response) //solicitud que se repide varias veces
                  this.friends = response
              }, error => {
                 console.log(error)})
    }}

    initialFriendsLoad() { //carga incial de datos en el BehaviorSubject
          this.listaService.loadFriends()
    }
```

y es ese show friends que hace la petición exponencialmente cada que la uso, como se muestra, que bien podría dejarlo así porque ya quedo, pero ya en fuera de entorno de práctica es mucho consumo de recursos y que la verdad no se como solucionar. Gracias y buen dia, buenas noches

Comment: Nunca cierras la suscripción. Las suscripciones no se ejecutan una única vez, se ejecutan cada vez que el observable emite, hasta que la cierras. Si usas una suscripción para algo que se ha de ejecutar una única vez, utiliza . unsubscribe a continuación o en el `pipe()` le metes `take(first())` por ejemplo, y se cerrará tras obtener el primer valor. Pero si cada vez llamas a `.subscribe()`, y nunca la cierras, cada vez que llegue un dato tendrás una suscripción más abierta, y no solo se repetirá el código, si no que al irte del componente se quedarán cargadas las suscripciones indefinidamente.

Comment: ¡Justamente ese era el problema..! Muchas gracias..!!